# How can I have two fixed width columns with one flexible column in the center?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to set up a flexbox layout with three columns where the left and right columns have a fixed width, and the center column flexes to fill the available space.

Despite setting up dimensions for the columns, they still seem to shrink as the window shrinks.

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

An additional thing I will need to do is hide the right column based on user interaction, in which case the left column would still keep its fixed width, but the center column would fill the rest of the space.

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: stretch;
    max-width: 1200px;
}

.column.left {
    width: 230px;
}

.column.right {
    width: 230px;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}

.column.center {
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="column left">
        <p>Anxiety was a blog series that ran in the New York Times Opinion section from January 2012 to July 2013. It featured essays, fiction, and art by a wide range of contributors that explored anxiety from scientific, literary, and artistic perspectives.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column center">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="100" height="100" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="column right">
        Balint Zsako
        <br/> Someone’s Knocking at My Door
        <br/> 01.12.13
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zDd2g/185/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5aor2b0x/11/

Answer (score 723, accepted):

Instead of using `width` (which is a suggestion when using flexbox), you could use `flex: 0 0 230px;` which means:

- `0` = don't grow (shorthand for `flex-grow`)
- `0` = don't shrink (shorthand for `flex-shrink`)
- `230px` = start at `230px` (shorthand for `flex-basis`)

which means: always be `230px`.

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/133rr51u/), thanks @TylerH

Oh, and you don't need the `justify-content` and `align-items` here.

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
#container {
    display: flex;
    x-justify-content: space-around;
    x-align-items: stretch;
    max-width: 1200px;
}
.column.left {
    width: 230px;
    flex: 0 0 230px;
}
.column.right {
    width: 230px;
    flex: 0 0 230px;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}
.column.center {
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - what does the 0 0 230px represent? And how would I adjust this if the right column gets hidden (so that the center column fills the width - 230px?

Comment: Hiding the right column shouldn't be a problem. I explained in the answer what the `0 0 230px` means.

Comment: In the current implementation (at least in Chrome), you also need to ensure that the middle column has `flex-grow` defined (as say 1). [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zDd2g/74/).

Comment: @baseten Not necessary in my Chrome 45 stable or Chrome 47 Canary on Windows. Why do you think it's necessary? Doesn't work for you? Spec change? Engine change?

Comment: @Rudie I also needed the flex-grow defined on the middle column for ti to work - not sure why though (Chrome 46) :/

Comment: why just width doesn't work? and I do need the flex: 0 0 230px;?

Comment: `flex-grow: 1` is still needed for fluid column in Chrome 53.
Otherwise, it wouldn't take the rest of width.
I suppose the answer should consider this fact.

Comment: For anyone still confused, `flex: 0 0 200px` acts the same as `width: 200px; flex-shrink: 0`.

Comment: supplying a `width: 200px ` and `flex: 0 0 200px` was enough for me

Comment: I have copied the Fiddle here in case Rudie lost it: https://jsfiddle.net/133rr51u/

Comment: You have to use `width: 230px` because if the content contains non-breakable items it will still grow.

Answer (score 63):

> Despite setting up dimensions for the columns, they still seem to shrink as the window shrinks.

An initial setting of a flex container is [**`flex-shrink: 1`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-shrink-property). That's why your columns are shrinking.

It doesn't matter what width you specify ([it could be `width: 10000px`](http://jsfiddle.net/zDd2g/186/)), with `flex-shrink` the specified width can be ignored and flex items are prevented from overflowing the container.

> I'm trying to set up a flexbox with 3 columns where the left and right columns have a fixed width...

You will need to disable shrinking. Here are some options:

```
.left, .right {
     width: 230px;
     flex-shrink: 0;
 }
```

OR

```
.left, .right {
     flex-basis: 230px;
     flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

OR, as recommended by the spec:

```
.left, .right {
    flex: 0 0 230px;    /* don't grow, don't shrink, stay fixed at 230px */
}
```

> [**7.2. Components of
>   Flexibility**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-components)
>
> Authors are encouraged to control flexibility using the `flex` shorthand
>   rather than with its longhand properties directly, as the shorthand
>   correctly resets any unspecified components to accommodate [common
>   uses](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common).

More details here: [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)

> An additional thing I need to do is hide the right column based on user interaction, in which case the left column would still keep its fixed width, but the center column would fill the rest of the space.

Try this:

```
.center { flex: 1; }
```

This will allow the center column to consume available space, including the space of its siblings when they are removed.

[**Revised Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zDd2g/187/)

Comment: Adding `flex: 1;` to the center `div` was enough, thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Compatibility with older browsers can be a drag, so be adviced.

If that is not a problem then go ahead.
Run the snippet. Go to full page view and resize. Center will resize itself with no changes to the left or right divs.

Change left and right values to meet your requirement.

Thank you.

Hope this helps.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

.column.left {
  width: 100px;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}

.column.right {
  width: 100px;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}

.column.center {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.column.left,
.column.right {
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="column left">this is left</div>
  <div class="column center">this is center</div>
  <div class="column right">this is right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.column.left {
    width: 230px;
    flex: 0 0 230px;
}

.column.right {
    width: 230px;
    flex: 0 0 230px;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}

.column.center {
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers but actually describe how this fixes the issue.