# HTML table full height and width with no scrolling

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I want to have a fixed height header, table with full height/width, and then some divs below that, preferably using flexbox.

How do I do that without getting scroll bars, so that everything takes up the full page?

Here's my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/1nyv4pqk/2/

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
.outter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.header {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 3em;
}
.content {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
.footerClass {
  background: yellow;
  height: 3em;
}
.tableClass {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
.tableClass th,
.tableClass td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
  <div class="header">This is a header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <table class="tableClass">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>COL 1</th>
          <th>COL 2</th>
          <th>COL 3</th>
          <th>COL 4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>This is some text in row 1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>This is some text in row 2</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>This is some text in row 3</td>
          <td>3,4,5</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>This is some text in row 4</td>
          <td>2,6,7</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
      Another Div
    </div>
    <div class="footerClass">
      This is a footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: all you're divs (except of the table) has fixed or dinamic height?

Comment: No, I want any divs between table and footer to have the ability to be a fixed height, take up vertical space as needed, or a percentage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `height: 100%` on your containers.

But in your `.outter` container you have these children:

```
.header {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 3em;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Here's how this plays out:

```
3em + 100% = vertical overflow = vertical scrollbar
```

Compensate for the `header` height. Make this adjustment:

```
.content {
  height: calc(100% - 3em);
  background-color: green;
}
```

A similar height adjustment must be applied to the child of `.content`:

```
.tableClass {
  margin: 10px;
  height: calc(100% - 3em - 20px - 19.0909px); /* height, less footer height, less margin
                                                  heights, less "Another Div" height */
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

In terms of the width, you have this:

```
.tableClass {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

The `margin` is adding to the `width: 100%`, causing a horizontal scroll.

Compensate for the overflow with: `width: calc(100% - 20px)`.

Also add `* { box-sizing: border-border; }`, so borders and padding are factored into `width` and `height` declarations.

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1nyv4pqk/3/)

Comment: How do you account for when the "Another Div" starts getting bigger? I get scroll bars again when I add a few paragraphs
https://jsfiddle.net/1nyv4pqk/4/

Comment: You can specify a height, so it can be factored into the container's  calculation. Or use flex properties.

Comment: I don't want to have to specify a height, so what do you mean by using flex properties?

Comment: The `flex-grow` property enables elements to occupy remaining space in a container. Here's an example for columns, that could just as easily be applied to rows: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23794713/3597276