# Inline position of 2 divs with firstchild with auto and second Child with 50%

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to build a slidepanel with js. For that I would like a div that resizes when slider opens.
Trying to do as following:

**html**

```
    <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="left">original content</div>
       <div class="right">sliding from right side</div>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
    .wrapper {width:100%;height:100%;position:relative;}
    .left {width:auto;height:100%;display:inline-block;}
    .right {width:50%;height:100%;}
```

This is the basic setup. I would like to have left take the full width. But when I click a button I want right to Slide in to 50%. Before adding js, I am trying to position the two divs, but it does not work. I tried with table cell, flex, ... I m just not able to get it right. Someone a good tip?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23794713/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#expand").on("click", function(){
  $(".wrapper").toggleClass("expand");
});
```

```css
.panel {
  height:100vh;
  transition: width .5s;
}
.left {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    Background:red;
    Text-align:right;
  }
  .right {
    float:right;
    width:0%;
    background:#ddd;
    overflow:hidden;
  }
.pos {right:5px;}

.wrapper.expand .left {width:50%;}
.wrapper.expand .right {width:50%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="panel left">
    original content
    <button class="pos" id="expand">Click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="panel right">sliding from right side</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Working solution. Only the js is not working because it is in conflict with the fullpage.js

Comment: This is the url

Comment: The name of the wrapper was bad. Changed the width in the meantime. Thanks so much!

Comment: You have `width:auto` instead of `width:100%` for .left in your site. Also, you have to change `.wrapper` to `.standorte-wrapper` in `$(document).ready`

Comment: Now I have a new challenge. The toggle for some reason changes my hash :D

Comment: What is your hash?

Comment: Should be #locations, but after toggle its just #. But I was using an <a>. Just changed it to button, like you did. Buttons are not handled by fullpage.js. So works fine now. Otherwise I had to write a script just to keep that link out of the fullpages..js hashflow. I might try later on to add build a specific link for each slide in will have on that page.