# When disabling class="img-responsive", bootstrap columns overlaps

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap, recently working on an Angular2 project, having a question to ask.

Currently I have a map-component left-hand side occupying 3 columns, however every time when I resize/shrink the browser, the image resizes/shrinks too. But I want the image to remain the fixed size whenever user resize the browser. So I delete the *class="img-responsive"* in the img tag. But those two components ended up overlapping when I shrink the browser. I am wondering why and could anyone please help me out.

For base app-component:

```
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <legend-component class="legend-component"></legend-component>
        <map-component></map-component>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9">
        <sidebar-component></sidebar-component>
        <table-component></table-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the map-component, I have the corresponding map-template to render my image:

```
<div align="center" >
    <div class="row" id="images">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <img  class="img-responsive" [src]=getImageSource() height="90%"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For normal full-screen sized browser:
[image: Normal full screen]

Shrink the browser before disabling class="img-responsive":
[image: Shrink the browser before disabling class="img-responsive"]

Shrink the browser after disabling class="img-responsive":
[image: Shrink the browser after disabling class="img-responsive"]

Comment: To have a fixed width column next to a fluid column you would have to use `display:table`/`display:table-cell` or use flex styling. Flex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794713/flexbox-two-fixed-width-columns-one-flexible, Table: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28932886/8085668

Comment: What do you want is a column with a fixed width, I suppose. So you should not use col-md-3 for the left column, but write the proper width in the style. For the right side you could use something like "width: calc(100% - 400px)" (400 is the left col width)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the image to stay to a certain size, I'd suggest defining a fixed width/height for the image. img-responsive resizes the image to the size of it's container's width.

Answer (score 1):

Give the image a max width. The img-responsive mainly changes the picture's width.