# IE11: how to make two-column grid layout that the second column would fill both or one column, depending on whether the first column is displayed

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10, grid-layout

What I want to achieve, is to have two-column grid layout that behaves like this:

if `display` property of `col 1` set to `inline` - layout should be rendered as follows:

```
+------+--------------+
|      |              |
|      |              |
|  c   |      c       |
|  o   |      o       |
|  l   |      l       |
|      |              |
|  1   |      2       |
|      |              |
|      |              |
+------+--------------+
```

in case if `display` property of `col 1` is set to `none` - `col 2` should occupy both columns:

```
+---------------------+
|                     |
|                     |
|          c          |
|          o          |
|          l          |
|                     |
|          2          |
|                     |
|                     |
+---------------------+
```

In Chrome and Firefox, I was able to achieve it via following CSS:

```
#content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15% minmax(85%, 1fr);
}

.col-1 {
  background: #D2691E;
  /* display: none; */
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
}

.col-2 {
  background: #191970;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
  grid-column-start: auto;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}
```

[Demonstration on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfo4qk9dv2ua5iksttbnqx64c/byqhhy3t/)

---

Though, I need the same to work in IE11, and it gets trickier here. I have read [this](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/11/26/should-i-try-to-use-the-ie-implementation-of-css-grid-layout/) and looked through [this one](https://24ways.org/2012/css3-grid-layout/), articles on grid implementation in IE10 and IE11.

`col 1` will eventually be a menu, so I've prepared a demo with button that intended to hide/show it via toggling the `display` property (which works as expected in Chrome and Firefox and doesn't work in IE11):

```js
function toggleDisplay() {
 var menu_div = document.getElementById('menu');
  if (menu_div.style.display === '' || menu_div.style.display === 'none') {
   menu_div.style.display = 'inline'
  } else {
   menu_div.style.display = 'none' 
  }
}
```

```css
#content {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  
  -ms-grid-columns: 15% minmax(85%, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns:  15% minmax(85%, 1fr);
  
  -ms-grid-rows: 1fr;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


.menu {
  background: #D2691E;
  display: none;
  
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  
  -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;

}

.content-area {
  background: #191970;
  
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  
  -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
  
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  grid-column-start: auto;
  
  -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id='content'>
<div class='menu' id='menu'></div>
<div class='content-area'>
<button onclick=toggleDisplay() >Show/hide 'display:none'</button>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

[Code above on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfo4qk9dv2ua5iksttbnqx64c/a2ssxvLk/)

I have also tried different method of toggling 'menu' - via moving it outside the view, with the same result (works in Chrome, Firefox not in IE11, though it toggles the menu in IE, at least):

```js
function toggleLeft() {
  var menu_navigation = document.getElementById('menu');
  if (menu_navigation.style.position === 'fixed' || menu_navigation.style.position === '') { 
    open();
    stopAnimation();
  } else {
    close();
  }
}

function close() {
  var menu_navigation = document.getElementById('menu');
  if (menu_navigation.style.position !== 'fixed') {
    menu_navigation.style.position = 'fixed';
    menu_navigation.style.left = '-15%';
    menu_navigation.style.witdh= '100%';
    menu_navigation.style.height = '100%';
  }  
}

function open() {
  var menu_navigation = document.getElementById('menu');
  if (menu_navigation.style.position !== 'relative') {
    menu_navigation.style.position = 'relative';
    menu_navigation.style.left = '0';
    menu_navigation.style.widh = 'auto';
    menu_navigation.style.height = 'auto';
  }
}
```

```css
#content {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  
  -ms-grid-columns: 15% minmax(85%, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns:  15% minmax(85%, 1fr);
  
  -ms-grid-rows: 1fr;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


.menu {
  background: #D2691E;
  position: fixed;
  left: -15%;
  height: 100%;

  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  
  -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;

}

.content-area {
  background: #191970;
    
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  
  -ms-grid-row-span: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
  
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
  grid-column-start: auto;
  
  -ms-grid-column-span: 2;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id='content'>
<div class='menu' id='menu'></div>
<div class='content-area'>
<button onclick=toggleLeft() >Show/hide 'left: -15%'</button>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

[Code above on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfo4qk9dv2ua5iksttbnqx64c/arkbpyLL/)

---

I have tried setting `-ms-grid-column` to `auto` for [first (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/mfo4qk9dv2ua5iksttbnqx64c/a2ssxvLk/1/) and [second (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/mfo4qk9dv2ua5iksttbnqx64c/arkbpyLL/1/) (I guess this one is as close as I could get to the required result) examples above, though desired result still not achieved.

My questions are:

1. What is the recipe to achieve desired grid layout in IE11, with plain CSS (i.e. without using pre-processors etc.)?
2. Is grid a good approach to use giving that I need an IE11 support, or some other approach is advised (if so, what might it be)?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23794713/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `attribute` selector to assign styling to the `.content-area` element:

```
.content-area{
    grid-column-start: 1;
}
#menu[style="display: block"] + .content-area{
    grid-column-start: auto;
}
```

Or, since you're already applying inline styling with JS, you could add and remove the inline grid styling on the content-area element in your `open` and `close` functions.

If this is a general question on using a grid alternative on IE11 - you could look at the [modernizr JS library](https://modernizr.com/), and use an alternative table layout styling if the browser does not support css-grid.