# Bootstrap 3: create 2 blocks with their own content in the same line with bootstrap 3 container

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Need to get such result:

[image: how can I place red blocks inline with container?]

Any solution with central block width = fixed container width. Red blocks width depends on user screen size.

If it's a trouble with HTML+CSS then js variant.

Comment: I think, you need to use `display:flex` property.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23794713/6191987

Comment: @vishnu Thanks! trying to use the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex` for this & with `calc` from CSS3. However, you still need to adjust `max-width` based on `bootstrap breakpoints` of `.container` class.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.left {
  max-width: calc(calc(100% - 720px)/2);
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}

.container {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.right {
  max-width: calc(calc(100% - 720px)/2);
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  </div>
  <div class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I searched for solution only for big screens so my fiddle is: https://jsfiddle.net/GrinderZ/pd05qasn/21

Comment: Then I think the fiddle is just fine for that :D

Answer (score 0):

as i can see red blocks are 1/2 width of blue one so it can go like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3> LEFT </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6> CENTER </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3> RIGHT </div>
</div>
```

Or if you want to hide red blocks on phone sizes you can put `hidden-xs` instead of `col-xs-3` and put `col-xs-12` in center div instead of `col-xs-6`

It all depends on your wish what will it do on small screens.

Comment: Edited question:
central block width = container width;
Red blocks width depends on user screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this, but it's not an orthodox method:

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <p>something red here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 container">
        <p>something green here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <p>something red here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also nothing stops you from adding your container inside your middle col like this:

```
<div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <p>something red here</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="container">
             <p>Your new row/cols can be inserted here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <p>something red here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

for smaller screens you should modify your classes according to `col-md-*`, `col-sm-*` and `col-xs-*` . Also check the official [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/)

**EDIT:** If you want to always have the middle container (i.e. 60% width) and the sidebars resized according to screen resolution you can do the following:

- You can add a new class in your container so it is like this: `<div class="col-lg-6 container myclass">` , then you can override the bootstrap css with your new class in your `custom.css` file, i.e.:

  .myclass{
   width: 60%!important;
  }
  Next step is to create media queries for your desirable resolutions like this:

  `@media (max-width: 1024px){
    .myclass{
      width: 60%!important;
  }`

  `@media (max-width: 768px){
    .myclass{
      width: 60%!important;
  }`

And so on... Check about media queries [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) , but you can find more on the web

Comment: In such variant central div width=50% and red blocks width=25% (styles from bootstrap css for col-lg-*). But I need fixed width container in the center.

Comment: So you want for example your sidebars to be resized but maintain your container to same width always ?

Comment: Yes. sidebars needs to be resizable