# Make two columns pixel-perfect in CSS using Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have two columns within a flexbox container that needs to be pixel perfect in term of their width.

```
<Column1 classname="col-sm-4">

<Column2 classname="col-sm-8>
```

I need Column1 to be at 327 pixel, and Column2 to take up the remainder of the width on that same row of Column1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745051/fill-the-remaining-height-or-width-in-a-flex-container

Comment: See this reference. I think it'll help.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23794791/11168176

Comment: Welcome! So what have you tried to do this? Seems like `flex` child properties like `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` are your friends.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to use flex-grow, flex-shrink, and flex-basis property to achieve the right layout